# Link shared library to another shared library

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, shared-libraries

I have one c++ Project that contains the principal binary that is : prog.CGI.
This is linked to one shared library called : Core.so,
I'd like to know if I can also link another shared library called : ext.so to Core.so because ext.so use structures defined into Core.so.

Comment: You can, but you don't need to provided that any executable that links against them has its build file linking against the dependent library before the one it depends on, in this case ext.so before Core.so.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, shared libraries can be linked to other shared libraries, and commonly are. You can use `ldd` to explore dependencies between them.